# DOMPDF Font Installer/Converter Not Working

Tags: unicode, converters, dompdf

I have DOMPDF working and running properly except that I can't install/convert the Arial Unicode font which my customer wants to use (with subsetting).  When I go into the setup, authenticate, and try to install ARIALUNI.TTF I get the following PHP warnings:

> Notice: Undefined index: family in C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.9\www\mysite\pdfmaker\www\controller.php on line
>   21
>
> Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.9\www\mysite\pdfmaker\www\controller.php on line
>   22
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.9\www\mysite\pdfmaker\www\controller.php on line
>   24

As you can see, that is running the utility from a WAMP.  When I try to run the utility off the server itself, I can't login. It keeps asking for my username/password (though the same username/password work in the WAMP environment.)

Furthermore, I have found the web-based font converter here: http://eclecticgeek.com/dompdf/load_font.php.  When I try to convert Arial Unicode there, it just loads for a bit, then the screen refreshes, and no dialog comes up for the .zip download, though this utility has worked for me for other fonts.

Does anyone have any idea why I'm having these problems and what a possible solution would be.  Has anyone else had trouble generating the .ufm file for Arial Unicode? I'm running the latest version of DOMPDF.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would get those errors, as they're basically related to the content posted from the form. What version of dompdf are you using? Did you try the offline load_font.php script?

Comment: FYI, the online font parser has limited resources at present and I'm considering taking it down. The tool was a necessity before we had a PHP-based font parser (when we were relying on binary parsers), but now it's redundant.

Comment: I'm using the latest version of DOMPDF - dompdf_0-6-0_beta3.  I have tried using the load_font script in the command prompt.  I go to the directory where both load_font.php and ARIALUNI.ttf are in and I type in "load_font.php ArialUni ARIALUNI.ttf" and instead of running the script, it just opens load_font.php in Editra, the software I use to code.  Is my syntax wrong?

Comment: Since nothing seems to work for me, as an alternate solution, would someone mind converting ArialUni.ttf to a .utf file and upload it somewhere so that I can download it?

Comment: If typing in the name of a PHP script causes it to open then you don't have those files associated with the PHP interpreter. You'll have to type in something like `php.exe load_font.php ARIALUNI.ttf`. You may also need to include the full path to php.exe. There are also some other options you may have to include to get things running correctly, but try that to start.

Comment: If you post the file online somewhere I can grab a copy and prepare it for you. Or I can temporarily increase the resource available to my server.

Comment: You're right, I don't have PHP installed on my local machine.  I downloaded the files from PHP.net, as well as the Wix installer, but can't seem to figure out how to install it.

Comment: The font can be found here [ArialUni](http://www.absolute.com.tw/pdfmaker/lib/fonts/ARIALUNI.TTF). Do you mind converting it to .utf for me and posting it somewhere I can download it?

Comment: You can find the font, .UFM, and updated base dompdf_font_family_cache.php [here](http://eclecticgeek.com/dompdf/fonttemp/arialuni.zip). I should note that this font is **huge**. You'll want to enable font sub-setting otherwise your PDF files will be huge. I'm not sure if php-font-lib will parse this file on systems with limited resources. Actually, I'm not even sure you'll be able to use it with dompdf because of its size. I'd have to do some testing to find out.

Comment: Thank  you very much for the help.  When I use ArialUni with subsetting, I get the following error when  I open a .pdf:
"The font "ARIALUNI" contains a bad/BBox."  Do you have any idea what's causing this?  I've have unicode enabled and other Unicode fnots work fine...

Comment: But works ok without sub-setting?

Comment: No, even when subsetting is disabled I get the same error message. Any ideas?

Comment: URIALUNI.TTF had an uppercase extension while ARIALUNI.ufm had a lowercase extension.  I changed the TTF to ttf and now I get the following error: "Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 23299103 bytes) in /home/content/83/10151483/html/pdfmaker/lib/class.pdf.php on line 1388"

Comment: Oh, but that was when I turned subsetting off to test your question. Now I've turned it back on and it seems to be working just fine!  Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Yeah, the font is probably a bit too large to hold in memory while doing other things. We'll look at optimizing resource usage in a future release. Glad subsetting seems to work ok, was worried it would fail from memory issues.

Comment: It seems to work fine when viewing a couple of .pdfs (I'm using DOMPDF to generate invoices), but after opening several, it runs into the memory problem.  That's okay though, you're right, the font is just too large.  Thanks again!